# NamedParameterJdbcTemplate unit test

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing

How to create unit test of this service class:

```
@Service
public class PhoenixService implements IPhoenixService {
    private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PhoenixService.class);

    private static final String WHERE = " WHERE ";
    private static final String FROM = " FROM ";
    private static final String SELECT = "SELECT ";

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("phoenixNamedParameterJdbcTemplate")
    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate phoenixNamedParameterJdbcTemplate;

    @Override
    public List<Account> getInternalAccount(String accountNo) throws Exception {
        MapSqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();

        parameters.addValue("accountNo", accountNo);
        String queryGetId = SELECT + ACCOUNT_IDENTIFIER + FROM
            + "SCHEMA" + "."
            + ACCOUNT + WHERE
            + ACCOUNT_NUMBER_TEXT + " = :accountNo";
        List<Account> accounts = phoenixNamedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(queryGetId, parameters,
            new RowMapper());
        if (accounts.isEmpty()) {
            //SomeThing
        }
        return accounts;
    }
}
```

I try to search but none working.
Sorry I new to Java especially unit test
Additional info, my environment didnt allow connection to DB for unit test.
Thanks

Comment: Use an in memory database like h2

Comment: If you want avoid connection to DB, you can mock method result using e.g Mockito Framework